# Visual C++, Windows Update Interface (IUpdate) <wuapi.h>, get_MsrcSeverity

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, windows-update

I'm probably just blind, but I cannot see any errors here (and I am looking on this issue already for days now...)

I am trying to get the Patch Priority (Severity) from the Windows Update Interface using the following piece of code in Visual Studio:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <wuapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ATLComTime.h>
#include <wuerror.h>

using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


     HRESULT hr;
    hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    IUpdateSession* iUpdate;
    IUpdateSearcher* searcher;
    ISearchResult* results;
    BSTR criteria = SysAllocString(L"IsInstalled=0");

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UpdateSession, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUpdateSession, (LPVOID*)&iUpdate);
    hr = iUpdate->CreateUpdateSearcher(&searcher);

    wcout << L"Searching for updates ..."<<endl;
    hr = searcher->Search(criteria, &results); 
    SysFreeString(criteria);

    switch(hr)
    {
    case S_OK:
        wcout<<L"List of applicable items on the machine:"<<endl;
        break;
    case WU_E_LEGACYSERVER:
        wcout<<L"No server selection enabled"<<endl;
        return 0;
    case WU_E_INVALID_CRITERIA:
        wcout<<L"Invalid search criteria"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    IUpdateCollection *updateList;
    IUpdateCollection *bundledUpdates;
    IUpdate *updateItem;
    IUpdate *bundledUpdateItem;
    LONG updateSize;
    LONG bundledUpdateSize;
    BSTR updateName;
    BSTR severity;

    results->get_Updates(&updateList);
    updateList->get_Count(&updateSize);

    if (updateSize == 0)
    {
        wcout << L"No updates found"<<endl;
    }

    for (LONG i = 0; i < updateSize; i++)
    {
        updateList->get_Item(i,&updateItem);
        updateItem->get_Title(&updateName);

        severity = NULL;
        updateItem->get_MsrcSeverity(&severity);
        if (severity != NULL) 
        {
            wcout << L"update severity: " << severity << endl;
        }

        wcout<<i+1<<" - " << updateName << endl;

        // bundled updates
        updateItem->get_BundledUpdates(&bundledUpdates);
        bundledUpdates->get_Count(&bundledUpdateSize);

        if (bundledUpdateSize != 0) 
        {
            // iterate through bundled updates
            for (LONG ii = 0; ii < bundledUpdateSize; ii++) 
            {
                bundledUpdates->get_Item(ii, &bundledUpdateItem);
                severity = NULL;
                bundledUpdateItem->get_MsrcSeverity(&severity);
                if (severity != NULL) 
                {
                    wcout << L" bundled update severity: " << severity << endl;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    ::CoUninitialize();
    wcin.get();


    return 0;
}
```

So here's the issue: `updateItem->get_MsrcSeverity(&severity);` is not returning anything. If I catch the result code with an `HRESULT` it always returns `S_OK`.

Link to MSDN IUpdate MsrcSeverity: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386906(v=vs.85).aspx

Can you see what I am doing obviously wrong or is the `get_MsrcSeverity` function currently broken?

@EDIT: Changed the code to iterate through "BundledUpdates" as suggested.

@EDIT2: the code now outputs the severity value of the `updateItem` as well as the `bundledUpdatesItem`, but it's always `NULL`.

I also know there is one important update waiting for my computer - regarding to Windows Update in the control panel. It is KB2858725.

@EDIT3: Okay, it turns out, KB2858725 is no security update and therefore has no severity rating by Microsoft. But how does Microsoft Windows Update now categorize the updates in "important" and "optional" like you can see it in control panel's update?

Thank you for any hints!
// Markus

Answer (score 3):

I've been struggling with the exact same problem for hours now...  I finally figured out that Microsoft only seems to set the MsrcSeverity value on some updates.  For general Windows updates, it's usually null.  For most security updates it's set to one of:

- "Critical"
- "Moderate"
- "Important"
- "Low"

It seems as though the "Unspecified" value is never used, though it is documented in MSDN ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.updateservices.administration.msrcseverity(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.updateservices.administration.msrcseverity%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

I wrote a small C# program to list all available updates and their reported severity.  It requires a reference to WUApiLib:

```
using System;
using WUApiLib;

namespace EnumerateUpdates
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var session = new UpdateSession();
            var searcher = session.CreateUpdateSearcher();
            searcher.Online = false;

            // Find all updates that have not yet been installed
            var result = searcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 And IsHidden=0");
            foreach (dynamic update in result.Updates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(update.Title + ": " + update.Description);
                Console.WriteLine("Severity is " + update.MsrcSeverity);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Look for bundled updates in the list. The bundled updates does not have some properties or methods as described on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page.

> Remarks
>
> If the BundledUpdates property contains an IUpdateCollection, some
>   properties and methods of the update may only be available on the
>   bundled updates, for example, DownloadContents or CopyFromCache.

The update you are processing in is a bundled update. Extract the individual updates from this bundle, it will have the property you are looking out for.

The `IUpdate` interface has a method `get_BundledUpdates` which gets you a `IUpdateCollection` if the size of this collection is greater then 0, this is a bundled update.

Comment: thank you for the hint! I added your advise to my code and it does find a bundled update, I then iterate through the bundled updates list, but it still returns "bad btr" for `get_MsrcSeverity()` within the "bundledUpdates" iteration ...

Comment: I think i missed out telling you one more point, severity is associated with Security Updates and not other type of updates..
So if the given update is a security update you should find the severity..

Comment: Okay thanks. But I know I have one important update (regarding to Windows Update in Control Panel) - it is KB2858725 (.NET Framework Update)

Comment: Most of the times the title of a security update will start with a line saying "Security Update for..."

But this update has a title as,
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 for Windows 7 x64-based Systems (KB2858725)

Comment: Hmm, this is what I thought too - but why does Windows then show this as an "important" Update in Control Panel - and how can I grab this info? `get_DownloadPriority` returns something different, I already tried that :) Thank for all your efforts and help so far!

Comment: @MarkusSteindl did u get the download priority??
I am facing problems in getting the CVE-ID, have you got it.

Comment: Yes, the downloadPriority was working, but I did not use it as you could not tell if it is an important or normal update when only looking onto the downloadPriority.